# RequestURI strips 'dot' in API link asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

I spent complete day to check what's happening and trying to fix unfortunately I am unable to find so seeking here for help. I didn't even get any answers from online when searched.

**issue.**

I have a API url

```
https://../../something/cycle/makes/A.B.C./models?modelYear=2017
```

so here 'A.B.C.' is one of the model I have and when I try to send this URL to `GetAsync()` method then the last 'dot' from 'A.B.C.' is striped and sent that as RequestURI which leads to 0 data since it is expecting 'A.B.C.' and it is sending 'A.B.C' here is the link which looks.

```
https://../../something/makes/A.B.C/models?modelYear=2017
```

if you observer there is no 'DOT' in the end of 'A.B.C'.

can anyone help me what I should be doing to get dot in the end.

any help is appreciated.

**UPDATE-1**

```
HttpResponseMessage response = new HttpResponseMessage();
            response = httpClient.GetAsync(sGetURL).Result
```

sGetURL contain this `https://../../something/cycle/makes/A.B.C./models?modelYear=2017`. i.e. with 'dot'.

so I can see the stripped link in response variable i.e. without 'dot'.

PS
I even tried escape sequence adding extra slash and it is not working.

Comment: @mjwills I thought it is straight forward question so didn't add any, please check it now it is under Update-1.

Answer (score 0):

I Have same issue.In your web.config use this `runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"` in modules under `<system.webserver>`

```
    <system.webServer>
 <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
      <remove name="FormsAuthentication"/>

      <remove name="ApplicationInsightsWebTracking" />
      <add name="ApplicationInsightsWebTracking" type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web.ApplicationInsightsHttpModule, Microsoft.AI.Web" preCondition="managedHandler" />
    </modules>
</system.webServer>
```

Comment: I think I used this part in config file.. which I got when browsed. however I can still take a look at it. I will update you.

Comment: This didn't work for me. thanks for your help though.